# Won't check if user exist using executeScalar()

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I want to check if a user already exist inside my MySQL database. i did insert a user inside a database, and want to check if this user exist. 
When a user insert something inside the textbox i want it to validate the username. I did also try: OnTextChanged="TextBoxUN_TextChanged" and copied the code inside the TextBoxUN_TextChanged.

here is my code so far.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack) {
           string server = "wisteria.arvixe.com";
           string database = "greenhouse";
           string uid = "******";
           string password = "******";
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
            database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            string cmd = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM registration WHERE Username='" + TextBoxUN.Text + "'";
            MySqlCommand userExist = new  MySqlCommand(cmd, connection);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(userExist.ExecuteScalar().ToString());               
            connection.Close();
            if (temp == 1)
            {
                Response.Write("User already exist..!!!");
            }
        }

    }
```

Hope anyone can help. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: I am not receiving the response: Response.Write("User already exist..!!!"); I did execute a query in my database. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM registration WHERE Username='myname'. I get 1. I know that temp is = 1. but i just can't get this response printed out

Comment: Are you sure that the `temp` variable is 1? Add a `Response.Write(temp)` to make sure. It could return an integer bigger than 1.

Comment: yea i am sure. i did add Response.Write(temp) and got 1

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    string server = "wisteria.arvixe.com";
    string database = "greenhouse";
    string uid = "******";
    string password = "******";
    string connectionString;
    connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
    database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        string cmd = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM registration WHERE Username='" + TextBoxUN.Text + "'";
        MySqlCommand userExist = new  MySqlCommand(cmd, connection);
        object obj = userExist.ExecuteScalar();

        int temp = -1;

        if (obj != DBNull.Value)
        {
           temp = Convert.ToInt32(obj);  
        }             

        if (temp == 1)
        {
            Response.Write("User already exist..!!!");
        }

        connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: I did try with no luck.
I will try to add a unique key inside my database, maybe it would solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

replace this line:

```
int temp = Convert.ToInt32(userExist.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

with this line:

```
int temp = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```